# Where does the gallery shortcode gets its attachments from?

Tags: attachments, gallery, media-library

I know that media are an attachment post type that are children to a post, but how are galleries stored in WordPress?

Comment: You should ask the other way around: "Where does the gallery shortcode gets its attachments from?" ;)

Comment: @kaiser good point.  I'm working on a gallery/album plugin and I'm doing research on how WordPress currently handles them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This completely depends on how your gallery shortcode looks like.

If you replaced it with something custom, then you'll have to take a look at the plugin (or the theme).

The default gallery shortcode gets it from a query:

```
$query_args = array(
     'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    ,'post_type'      => 'attachment'
    ,'post_mime_type' => 'image'
    ,'order'          => $order
    ,'orderby'        => $orderby
);
```

Then it decides to add additional args for either `include` or `exclude`.

Here're the 3 scenarios that add the additional/non-shared arguments.

```
'include' => preg_replace( '/[^\D,]+/', '', $include )
'exclude' => preg_replace( '/[^\D,]+/', '', $include )
// default
'post_parent' => $id
```

Comment: As I thought.  Thanks for the clarification.  So basically galleries are just images that are attached to a post; 1 gallery per post and since images are children to a post, you can only really attach the images to just one post at a time.

Comment: Not really. They're referenced in the post meta table. So every post with an image/a gallery has the attachment IDs in its meta data.

Comment: Oh, they are?  Some more research to do.  Thank you again, @kaiser